# What is causing my kafka log segments to be deleted?

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, segments

These are my settings

`log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000` checks when logs can be deleted

`log.retention.hours=168` how old a non active segment must be before it gets deleted

`log.retention.ms=null` how old a non active segment must be before it gets deleted

`log.retention.bytes=-1` how big a non active segment must be before it gets deleted

`segment.ms=30000` how old segments have to be before the log gets rotated.

from what I gather, a new log segment should be created every 30 seconds when possible(this is happening). But why are old segments deleted? Shouldn't it wait 168 hours(since log.retention.ms is null)?

Comment: There are two policies by which Kafka decides whether a log segment will be deleted: time-based policy and size-based policy. It might be due to the fact that segment size hits the threshold.

Comment: Do you know what those properties are called? also I don't believe this is the issue as I am sending 3-10 bytes of info(1 character each message).

Comment: How long is it waiting to delete the old segments?

Comment: Seems to be random. I looked at the log and it's random from 5,10,20 minutes.... seems to be increasing before segments are cleaned up though

Comment: What's the size of your segment files before it got deleted? And also check if you set `cleanup.policy` to 'clean'  for the topic.

Comment: figured it out. was not taking the property min.cleanable.dirty.ratio into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a property I was not looking into "min.cleanable.dirty.ratio". After accounting for that, I was able to trigger compaction pretty regularly.